# jquery autocomplete result as two results from json/php

Tags: jquery, json, tag-it

Is there a way to get a single result from a json query.

Say I get an input from json that's `Domestic Dog:Canis lupus familiaris`. Since it's going to be in a tag, I want both sides to be related. So, is there a way I can show the: `Domestic Dog` in on textarea and `Canis lupus familiaris` in another.

I need them to be in tags so if I remove the `Domestic Dog` it will remove `Canis lupus familiaris` in the other. Only one field is editable (so it needs to be one way).

I thought about splitting the result, but that would make it into two separate fields, which is not working (yes, I've tried it using `$.split()`.

Comment: Well, that's not valid JSON, first off.  JSON is in this sort of format: `{ elementName : value }`  You should be able to do a `JSON.parse(data)` on your data and it shouldn't blow up.  Also I don't even think there's a `$.split()` function, [this is what you're actually looking for.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Don't worry about the return from the server. It's in proper JSON format (i.e it's `{"label":"Domestic Dog","value":"Canis lupus familiaris"}`. What I did was purposely combine the two last results into one so that I could manipulate it in jQuery properly. That is: `{"label":"Domestic Dog","value":"Domestic Dog:Canis lupus familiaris"}`. As you can see the Value in the second result has both instances together. What I want to do is show the first half in one textarea and the second half in the other.

Comment: Why in the world would you put two values into a single value?  Don't do that.  That's your problem.

Comment: If you need tags, do something like this: `{label : ['canine', 'cat', 'etc'], value: 'Canis lupus whatever'}`

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica I'm just trying to put related tags into two different outputs with results from a json query, not a single tag field. That's why this I'm having trouble.

Comment: Then you need to include actual code.  There's no telling where you have errors at otherwise.

Comment: Well it would seem my stolen answer was good enough to fix your problem.  Cheers!

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Hm... must've clicked on that on accident. I'm trying to go through the .js to split the result somewhere in the code. Might have to create a new function to do just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a second function within the jQuery code.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces It involves modifying the actual jQuery.js file, so I didn't think it would work for the general audience as it is now very specific to my kind of code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert your JSON string into a JavaScript object? Then you can use it as you wish.